# Obtener nombre de variable en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
function Class(){
  this.getInstanceName = function(){
    // ¿Es posible obtener el nombre de la instancia? algo como:
    return getInstanceName();
  };
}

var classInstance = new Class();

// debe imprimir: classInstance
console.log(classInstance.getInstanceName());
```

¿Es posible obtener el nombre de la instancia `classInstance` en JavaScript?

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres conocer el nombre de la variable? Cómo se llame la variable no debería influir en la funcionalidad de la aplicación

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Mayormente por curiosidad, aunque hace poco tenía un ejemplo de una colección más o menos así: `[instanceOne, instanceTwo]` y cada vez que recorriera la colección quería diferenciar a cada instancia. Pero ahora me parece mejor una de las sugerencias de las respuestas, que es agregar un atributo para diferenciar cada instancia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hace un tiempo hice esta clase que exporta 2 métodos: Uno que retorna el nombre de la función (el nombre en la declaración)

`getFunctionName(function myFunction(a, b, c){})` que retorna "myFunction" o una cadena vacía si es una función anónima.

y este que retorna el nombre de los parámetros:

`getParameterNames(function myFunction(a, b, c){})` que retorna "[a, b, c]"

Ten en cuenta que si lo usas así:

```
var fn = function myFunction(a, b, c) {};
getFunctionName(fn);
```

También retorna `myFunction`, dado que tiene en cuenta la declaración de la función, no el alias con que se pasa. Por lo tanto no va a funcionar como pides, pero es lo se puede hacer en javascript.

Estos métodos básicamente parsean la función para obtener los datos (utilizan `function.toString` para hacerlo). Incluye algo de soporte de ECMAScript 2015.

```
var reflection = (function () {
    'use strict';

    var stripComments = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg,
        argumentNames = /([^\s,]+)/g,
        reflection = {};

    /**
     * Checks if 'expr' is a function 
     * @param {} expr 
     * @returns {} 
     */
    function isFunction(expr) {
        return typeof expr === 'function';
    }

    /**
     * Gets the function parameter names as an Array.
     * 
     * usage example: getParameterNames(function (a,b,c){}); // ['a','b','c']
     * @param {} func the function. 
     * @returns {} An ordered array of string with the parameters names, or an empty array if the function has no parameters.
     */
    function getParameterNames(func) {
        var fnStr = func.toString().replace(stripComments, '');
        var result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(') + 1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(argumentNames);
        if (result === null)
            result = [];
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the function name.
     * 
     * @param {} func the function. 
     * @returns {} the name of the function, empty string if is an anonymous function. 
     */
    function getFunctionName(func) {
        if (!isFunction(func)) throw new TypeError('"func" must be a function.');
        // ECMAScript 2015
        if (func.name) {
            return func.name;
        }
        // old fashion way
        var fnStr = func.toString().substr('function '.length),
            result = fnStr.substr(0, fnStr.indexOf('('));
        return result;
    }

    // Module Exports
    reflection.isFunction = isFunction;
    reflection.getFunctionName = getFunctionName;
    reflection.getParameterNames = getParameterNames;
    return reflection;
}());
```

Comment: Entonces, ¿básicamente no se puede obtener el nombre del alias y únicamente se puede obtener el nombre de la clase?

Comment: No que yo sepa.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes extraer el nombre de la función desde un stack trace de un objeto `Error`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo() {
    var e = new Error();
    var me = e.stack.match(/at ([a-z0-9_.]+) \(/i);
    console.log("me = " + me[1]);
}
foo();   
</script>
```

Quizás quieras poner esa funcionalidad en una función común, y entonces deberías buscar la segunda función en el stack trace:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calledFrom() {
    var e = new Error(); 
    stack = e.stack.split("\n");
    caller = stack[2].match(/at ([a-z0-9_.]+) \(/i);
    return caller[1];   
}
function foo() {
    console.log("Mi nombre es " + calledFrom());
}
foo();
var obj = {};
obj.bar = foo;
obj.bar();
</script>
```

La respuesta en el console:

> Mi nombre es foo
>   Mi nombre es Object.foo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, mi pregunta está mas orientada a instancias de clases, por ejemplo en `var fooBar = foo` la sentencia `calledFrom()` debería imprimir `fooBar`

Comment: @learnercys: Dejame pensarlo... quizás puedo pensar en una solución para añadir mañana.

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer de momento no hay forma de lograr obtener el nombre de la variable en JavaScript, encontré varias fuentes que coinciden con ello y las cito a continuación. En cambio encontré una alternativa tomada de un código de PHP que traducida a JavaScript; funciona únicamente para las variables globales en los navegadores (por el objeto `window`).

#### Solución (alternativa)

```
function getNameVar(v) {
    for (var key in window) {
        if (window[key] === v)
        return key;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Modo de empleo:

```
var a = '123',
    b = 'abc';

getNameVar(a); // "a"
```

**Idea original en:** [How to get a variable name as a string in PHP? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255335/2578107)

---

**Traducción:** [Javascript get name of instance of class - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12972451/2578107)

Las variables en JavaScript son de valor primitivo o referencia a un objeto. Donde el valor es una referencia, entonces la **cosa** referenciada no tiene idea del "nombre" de la variable que lo contiene.

Considera:

```
var foo = new Cosa();
var bar = foo;
```

Entonces ahora `foo.getInstanceName()` ¿qué debería retornar? o incluso:

```
(new Cosa()).getInstanceName();
```

Si tu quieres que las instancias tenga un nombre, entonces dales una propiedad y configura el valor que quieres que tenga.

---

Otras fuentes de apoyo:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404057/determine-original-name-of-variable-after-its-passed-to-a-function
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565031/get-the-name-of-a-variable-in-javascript
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276080/get-variable-names-with-javascript

Comment: "¿qué debería retornar?" es una pregunta? En el primer caso debería retornar `foo` en el segundo `null` o `undefined` supongo.

Comment: @learnercys añadí una función alternativa, espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: quiza deberias decir, "funciona _unicamente_ para variables globales en un navegador" ya que en nodejs. esto no funcionaria tampoco por que no existe el objeto window.